# Is it possible to download from my MSDN Subcription directly to my Azure File storage without an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an MSDN Subcription which allows me to download and install various Microsoft products.

I would like to download from there the Sql Server 2016 Developer edition. But for the reasons that are irrelevant for this question, I would like to keep the downloaded ISO file not on the local machine, but on an Azure File share I have in my Azure account.

Right now, I first download from MSDN to my machine and then upload to the Azure File Storage.

Wasteful, it would be much more efficient if I could somehow download it directly to Azure Files from MSDN.

I understand that if I had an Azure VM, that would be possible. But I do not. So, I am wondering if it is possible to do it anyway without an Azure VM.

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details. I’m assuming that you’ve some files sitting in a file storage account in one subscription that you wish to move to a file storage account in another subscription without downloading. Correct?

Comment: I edited the post. Is it better now?

Comment: Definitely better. Thanks! I have provided part answer to your problem.

Comment: Azure Files service is not tied to Virtual Machines. It's an SMB service, which you can mount to a local machine if you wanted to (though you'd have latency/throughput based on your internet connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part answer to your problem.

If the URL of the file you're trying to use (ISO for SQL Server 2016 Developer edition in your case) is public (i.e. if you paste the URL in browser's address bar for example, you should be able to access that file), then you don't have to download/reupload. Azure Storage provides asynchronous server-side copy functionality where a file can be created by copying from a publicly accessible resource.

For more about copy file, please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-file). Since you didn't mention any programming language, I provided reference to REST API. But you can simply use one of the available SDKs to accomplish this.

The reason I said part answer is because I don't know how you will access the link of the file programmatically.

Comment: Good enough for me.